# ninja: error: build.ninja: bad $-escape (literal $ must be written as $$)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, ninja

I am getting the following error while compiling [***SeqAn***](https://github.com/seqan/seqan) Framework:

```
1> [CMake] CMake Error:
1> [CMake]   Running
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]    'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe' '-C' 'C:/Users/pc/source/repos/seqan/out/build/x64-Clang-Debug' '-t' 'recompact'
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   failed with:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]    ninja: error: build.ninja:152: bad $-escape (literal $ must be written as $$)
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
1> 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' '/c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\pc\Source\Repos\seqan\out\install\x64-Clang-Debug" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\pc\Source\Repos\seqan" 2>&1"' execution failed with error: ''C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' '/c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\pc\Source\Repos\seqan\out\install\x64-Clang-Debug" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\pc\Source\Repos\seqan" 2>&1"' returned with exit code: 1'.
```

The following is my ***CMakeSettings_schema.json*** file:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Clang-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "clang_cl_x64_x64" ],
      "variables": []
    }
  ]
}
```

The following is the content of my ***build.ninja*** file from line # 152:

```
  COMMAND = cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\pc\source\repos\seqan\out\build\x64-Clang-Debug && C:\Users\pc\source\repos\seqan\out\build\x64-Clang-Debug\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\alf.exe --write-ctd C:/Users/pc/source/repos/seqan/out/build/x64-Clang-Debug/workflow_plugin_dir/descriptors/alf.ctd"
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you ask your question on their GitHub? The error is in CMakeLists.txt, perhaps they never configured SeqAn for Ninja.

Comment: Content of the file `build.ninja` is specific for your machine. For being able to start debugging of your problem we need at least to know content of the **erroneous line**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, where can I find it?

Comment: Probably, this file is in the build directory, or under `CMakeFiles` subdirectory in it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, check the edit, plz.

Comment: As far as I understand, you use Ninja with Visual Studio-compatible compiler. In that case, the line [util/cmake/SeqAnCtdSetup.cmake:71](https://github.com/seqan/seqan/blob/master/util/cmake/SeqAnCtdSetup.cmake#L71) could be a problem. This line uses substitution `$(ConfigurationName)` which works only with Visual Studio as a **built tool**. But [MSVC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/MSVC.html) variable, which protects given line, is set with MSVC-compatible **compiler**. You may try to comment out given line and configure the project again.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, sorry I made mistake. I added incorrect file content. Pleaze check the corrected line #152.

Comment: Ok, so it is clear that exactly `$(ConfigurationName)` is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may have fixed this issue by now, but what caused my bad $-escape error was an extra $ in one of the paths specified in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).